# max() of big nested lists

Tags: python, list, max, nested-lists

I encountered a quite odd problem while dealing with the max of a long list of lists of of pairs, such as

```
[
    [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1),...,(141,3)],
    ..., 
    [(12, 1), (36, 1), (91, 1), (92, 1), (110, 1),..., (180, 1)]
]
```

I am trying to get the maximum of the first element of all the pairs.
Pythonically, I was doing:

```
max([max(x) for x in list])[0]
```

which actually returns the correct number, IF the list is shorter than 281 lists.
In fact, as soon as the list is longer than 280, I get this message

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

So, for a long list

```
max([max(x) for x in list[0:280]])[0]
```

it's fine, while

```
max([max(x) for x in list[0:281]])[0]
```

breaks.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Could you provide a  [MCVE]?

Comment: Your sample with slices is invalid Python. Please provide a [mcve] that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: It was actually an empty list that somehow sneaked in during the process.
I didn't provide it right away because the creation process was kind of complicated and I couldn't easily boil it down to few lines. Anyways, the problem was actually trivial, so I might delete the question at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an empty list among your list of lists, at index 280. Slicing up to `[:280]` excludes it, and it is included with `[:281]`.

This is easily reproduced with a shorter sample:

```
>>> lsts = [
...     [(0, 1), (1, 1)],
...     [(2, 1), (3, 4)],
...     [(4, 1), (5, 1)],
...     [],  # empty at index 3
... ]
>>> max(max(x) for x in lsts)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
>>> max(max(x) for x in lsts[:3])  # include everything before index 3
(5, 1)
```

You can avoid the issue altogether by chaining your lists together, here using [`chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

max(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))[0]
```

This treats all nested lists as one long list, an empty list somewhere in between simply doesn't contribute to that new sequence.

Comment: Thank you, this was actually the problem. Somehow an empty list sneaked in during the creation process.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this?

```
max([max([t[0] for t in sl if t]) for sl in l if sl])
```

You can extract the first item from the beginning.  Empty lists and tuples are ignored.

EDIT

```
max([max([t for t in sl if t]) for sl in l if sl])[0]
```

is more efficient.

Comment: It's faster to use subscription just *once*. The `tuple.__gt__` method can test contents in C code much faster than Python bytecode can run subscription on each element.